# Smart Assistant

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit

I have currently designed a smart assistant in Android Studio and it is working on my App, voice communication with the user is essential in the production of this App so it is paramount that this feature works.

I was wondering if it was possible to open up the voice assistant alike to how we can communicate with Alexa by saying 'Alexa' - a wake up word.

As show in the code section below, I use a image to activate the smart assistant upon clicked - and then the user has a conversation accordingly. Is there a way it is possible as mentioned above so that the user can simply say something instead of clicking the image (imgspeech).

Appreciate your time. Thank you.

This is my .java file

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
private ArrayList<String> questions;
private String name, surname, age, asName;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private static final String NEW = "new";
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String AGE = "age";
private static final String AS_NAME = "as_name";
private static final String SURNAME = "surname";
private static final String COLOUR = "colour";
private ImageView imgbtnTorF, imgbtnQuizzes;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
    imgbtnQuizzes = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnQuizzes);
    imgbtnTorF = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnTorF);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    findViewById(R.id.imgSpeech).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listen();
        }
    });
    loadQuestions();

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "This language is not supported");
                }
                speak("Hello");
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed!");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadQuestions() {
    questions = new ArrayList<>();
    questions.clear();
    questions.add("Hello, what is your name?");
    questions.add("What is your surname?");
    questions.add("How old are you?");
    questions.add("Where do you live?");
    questions.add("What is your favourite colour?");
    questions.add("What is your favourite password you use?");
    questions.add("Remember if you are wondering what you can ask me, you can say the word information and i will help you");
    questions.add("That's all I had, thank you ");
}

private void listen() {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(homescreen.this, "Your device doesn't support Speech Recognition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void speak(String text) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

    } else {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> res = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String inSpeech = res.get(0);
            recognition(inSpeech);
        }
    }
}


private void recognition(String text) {
    Log.e("Speech", "" + text);
    String[] speech = text.split(" ");
    if (text.contains("hello")) {
        speak(questions.get(0));
    }
    //
    if (text.contains("my name is")) {
        name = speech[speech.length - 1];
        Log.e("THIS", "" + name);
        editor.putString(NAME, name).apply();
        speak(questions.get(1));
    }
    if (text.contains("my last name is")) {
        surname = speech[speech.length - 1];
        Log.e("THIS", "" + surname);
        editor.putString(SURNAME, surname).apply();
        speak(questions.get(2));
    }
    //This must be the age
    if (text.contains("years") && text.contains("old")) {
        String age = speech[speech.length - 3];
        Log.e("THIS", "" + age);
        editor.putString(AGE, age).apply();
        speak(questions.get(3));
```

Comment: Use pocketsphinx for the keyword recognition then switch to Android speech recognition for the question when the keyword is recognized by sphinx, Keep in my that battery will be consume if the device is listening for this keyword at all time,

Comment: @HoanNguyen I appreciate your insight and the negativity of using this feature, thank you